# Why doesn't tar change atime of files with zero bytes?

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I have to periodically archive and compress my files (`using tar -cvzf`), otherwise, the system administrator can deliberately delete my files with old access time (`atime`).

I run `tar -cvzf` over my files in order to compress and archive them; this process updates the `atime` because the files are accessed to be compressed.

However, I realized that any file with zero bytes even though it is accessed and compressed, it does not have the `atime` updated.

For instance, the file:
`-rw-r----- 1 user user     0 Sep 29 08:23 __init__.py`
is compressed, but the `atime`: (Sep 29) is not updated.

If the file has at least one (1) byte, then the `atime` is updated during the archiving process.

This is a problem for me because all my files with zero bytes can be deleted by the administrator.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure what system you're on, but this question likely belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com . stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Do you actually keep the archives? You don't need to make an archive to access the files. I would just use `find` with `touch -a`.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title. The title is "Why doesn't tar change the atime of files with zero bytes?" The answer is "Because atime is updated on read, but the code does a [`while (size_left > 0)`](https://github.com/Distrotech/tar/blob/273975bec1ff7d591d7ab8a63c08a02a285ffad3/src/create.c#L1030), and a zero-length file has a `size_left` of zero, so the `while` loop is skipped over, and no reads are issued.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -exec touch -a {} \;` will do the trick for the current directory. No need to make an archive just for this. The `.` can be replaced by the directory whose contents you want marked as accessed.